# sheafification and quasi-coheret sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My problem comes from this post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/467252/115619

The example he gave is $j_!\mathcal O_U$. But I think $j_!\mathcal O_U$ is the sheafification of the presheaf $V \to \mathcal O_X(V)$ if $V \subseteq U$, $V \to 0$ otherwise.

So I think after the sheafification, $j_!\mathcal O_U(V)=\mathcal O_U(U \cap V)$ for every $V \subseteq X$.

But that post said $j_!\mathcal O_U(X)=0$, hence it's not quasi-coherent.

-----------------------update-----------------

Let me try if I understand correctly. Let's call that presheaf $\mathcal F$. Assume $X$ is an affine variety.

If $V \subseteq X$ is an open affine subset such that $V \not\subseteq U$, $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$. Then $j_!\mathcal O_U(V)$ is a subset of $\cup_{p \in U} \mathcal F_p \cup_{p \not\in U} \mathcal F_p$.

But when $p \not\in U$, $\mathcal F_p=0$. So if $s \in j_!\mathcal O_U(V)$, $s(p)=0$ for $p \in V-U$.

Because $s$ vanishes on $V-U$, V is affine, then $s=0$ on $V$.

In that example, $X$ is an affine variety. So $j_!\mathcal O_U(X)=0$.

So if $X$ is an affine irreducible scheme, $j_!\mathcal O_U$ is already a sheaf. Am I right?

Comment: The sentence "So I think that ... " is wrong. Think more carefully about the speafification process.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Do you think my update is correct?