# Relationship between a sheaf and the sheaf we get after applying the coherator.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a quasi-compact and
quasi-separated scheme. Now, consider the forgetful functor $i$ from the category of quasi-coherant sheaves on $X$ to category of $O_X$-modules. 
$$i: Qcoh(X) \hookrightarrow Mod(X)$$ 
The right adjoint to this functor is called the coherator. 
$$Q :Mod(X) \rightarrow Qcoh(X)$$

My question is if $F \in Mod(X)$ be a sheaf, then is $Q(F)$ is a subsheaf of $F$ in the category $Mod(X)$? More precisely is it true that,
   $$i\circ Q(F)\subset F $$
If not, can it be true with some additional conditions ?

Basically, I am trying to understand the connection between $F$ and $Q(F)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the affine case?

Comment: In case $X = SpecA$ is affine, then $Q(F) = F(X)^{\sim}$. So, what we want is to see if  $F(X)^{\sim}(U) \subset F(U)$ for all $U \subset X$. Now, it is enough to show this for every affine $U$. Let $U = SpecB$. Then,  $F(X)^{\sim}(SpecB) = F(X) \otimes B$. So the question is $$F(X)^{\sim}(SpecB) \subset F(SpecB) $$ ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to me to be true in general. However, I am wondering if this can be true with some further conditions.

Comment: By looking at stalks: if $X$ is affine and $F$ is globally generated, then the morphism $i\circ Q(F)\to F$ is an epimorphism. Thus, to produce a counter-example it suffices to construct a non-quasi-coherent, but globally generated $\mathcal{O}_X$-module on an affine scheme.

Comment: Or you just look at the answers to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/467197/12885