# Is $\mathcal I$ a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme and $\mathcal I$ a sheaf of ideals of $\mathcal O_X$. Is $\mathcal I$ a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/467232/3217 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/467252/3217

Answer (score 4):

If I remember my algebraic geometry correctly, this should not hold in general, however, it holds precisely if $\mathcal{I}$ corresponds to a closed embedding of another scheme. Vakil has in his notes beautiful examples and exercises about precisely this subtlety, which I can only recommend:
http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf