# Reconciliation of definition of presentable module/quasi-coherent sheaf with the fact that all modules have free presentation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, definition, quasicoherent-sheaves

Presentable module is defined in nLab (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/presentable+module) as “the cokernel of a homomorphism of free modules”.

What I’m confused about is that, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_presentation, given a module $M$ over $R$, “a free presentation always exists”, so shouldn’t that mean any module is presentable?

So what would it look like for a module not to be presentable? Are there particular constraints on what sequences “count” that I’m missing? Or maybe $M$ isn’t always a “cokernel” in these sequences? Or maybe I’m muddling two different definitions?

Put another way, in the definition of a quasi-coherent sheaf (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_sheaf), we require the existence of a certain exact sequence
$$
\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus I}|_{U} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus J}|_{U} \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}|_{U} \longrightarrow 0 \,,
$$
but by the above, given that $\mathcal{F}|_{U}$ is by definition a module over $\mathcal{O}_X|_{U}$, shouldn’t such a sequence always exist?

Comment: Every module over a ring is presentable, but not every module over a sheaf of rings. That is, not every module is quasicoherent. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467197/examples-of-mathcalo-x-modules-that-are-not-quasi-coherent-sheaves

Comment: The nLab article should really make this clearer but since this is their whole thing they are talking in great generality about modules over rings in categories more general than $\text{Set}$, e.g. in categories of sheaves.

Comment: Is what @KevinArlin is calling a "module over a sheaf of rings" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_of_modules ? (which as of posting this unhelpfully has an empty definition section :) ) Which is a "module" in the "normal" sense when X is a single point? If so I think I can rewrite the statements above clearly delineating between these concepts and resolve the confusion

Comment: @lukemassa Yeah, I mean the same thing. If $X$ is a point then a sheaf of rings is uniquely determined by its ordinary ring of global sections and a sheaf of modules over that sheaf of rings is similarly determined by its ordinary module of global sections. In particular every sheaf of modules over a one-point ringed space is quasicoherent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here, as @kevinarlin pointed out, is I was confusing two notions of "modules": a module over a ring (an abelian group with a ring of scalars) and a sheaf of modules (aka a module over a sheaf of rings, which is a certain sheaf whose sections are modules of the first type).

These notions coincide when $X$ is a single point (since all the information there is is a single module, so we can "forget" the point and just look at the module over it.)

The nLab article was using the second definition (which @qiaochu-yuan points out is somewhat confusing).

The statement "there always exists a free presentation of a module" is only true of the first definition, not of the second, which corresponds with the existence of non-quasi-coherent modules.

So the exact sequence I wrote at the end was of the "second" type of modules, which is why it's not vacuously true.